# Why is my django snippet not working?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I put together a function to link to news items with django as a filter. It works on dev_appserver but on production server it returns `None` Can you tell me why it's not working? Should I investigate the except clause of the code where it currently just passes?

```
def news(n):
    url = os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST') if os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST') else os.environ['SERVER_NAME']
    tld = url[url.rfind('.'):]    
    try:        
        if url == 'localhost:8080':
            result = urlfetch.fetch('http://news.google.se/?output=rss')    
        elif tld != '.com' and tld != '.se' and tld != '.cl' :
            result = urlfetch.fetch('http://news.google.com'+tld+'/?output=rss') 
        else:      
            result = urlfetch.fetch('http://news.google.com/?output=rss')        
        if result.status_code == 200:
            dom = minidom.parseString(result.content)
            item_node = dom.getElementsByTagName("item")
            try:
                random_1=random.choice(item_node)
                rss1_link = random_1.childNodes[1].firstChild.data
                rss1_text = random_1.childNodes[0].firstChild.data
                return mark_safe('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (rss1_link, rss1_text))
            except IndexError,e:
                return ''
    except urlfetch.Error, e:
        pass

register.filter(news)
```

Update: Now it returns an empty string on production but locally it works. It's something else that status 200 on production:

```
def news(n):
    url = os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST') if os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST') else os.environ['SERVER_NAME']
    tld = url[url.rfind('.'):]    
    try:        
        if url == 'localhost:8080':
            result = urlfetch.fetch('http://news.google.se/?output=rss')    
        elif tld != '.com' and tld != '.se' and tld != '.cl' :
            result = urlfetch.fetch('http://news.google.com'+tld+'/?output=rss') 
        else:        
            result = urlfetch.fetch('http://news.google.com/?output=rss')        
        if result.status_code == 200:
            dom = minidom.parseString(result.content)
            item_node = dom.getElementsByTagName("item")
            try:
                random_1=random.choice(item_node)
                rss1_link = random_1.childNodes[1].firstChild.data
                rss1_text = random_1.childNodes[0].firstChild.data
                return mark_safe('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (rss1_link, rss1_text))        
            except IndexError,e:
                return ''
        else:
            return ''
    except urlfetch.Error, e:
        logging.error(str(e))
        return ''
```

EDIT: Here's the simplest reproduction that return a status 200 locally and a status 503 on production

```
def status(n):
    try:             
        result = urlfetch.fetch('http://news.google.com/?output=rss')       
        return str(result.status_code)
    except urlfetch.Error, e:
        return 'error'
```

Update: Here's the solution I currently use. It still needs improfement since there is a possibility for choosing 2 news items that are the same:

```
import random
def updateFeed(url):#to do, get srv from url and find number of entries
    srv = os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST') if os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST') else os.environ['SERVER_NAME']
    tld = srv[srv.rfind('.'):] 
    url = 'http://news.google.com/?output=rss'
    if srv.endswith('.com.br'):
        url = 'http://news.google.com.br/?output=rss'
    elif srv == 'localhost:8080' or srv.endswith('alltfunkar.com'):
        url = 'http://news.google.se/?output=rss'
    elif tld != '.com' and tld != '.se' and tld != '.cl' :
        url = 'http://news.google.com'+tld+'/?output=rss'
    query_args = { 'q': url, 'v':'1.0', 'num': '15', 'output': 'json' }
    qs = urllib.urlencode(query_args)
    loader = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load'
    loadurl = '%s?%s' % (loader, qs)
    logging.info(loadurl)
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url=loadurl,headers={'Referer': '...'})
    if result.status_code == 200:
        news = simplejson.loads(result.content) 

        """ not working, using random.randrange instead
        some_key = random.choice(news.keys())
        something = news[some_key]
        """
        i = random.randrange(0,10)#to do: instead of 10, it should be number of entries
        title = news[u'responseData'][u'feed'][u'entries'][i][u'title']
        link = news[u'responseData'][u'feed'][u'entries'][i][u'link']
    return mark_safe('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (link, title))
```

Comment: There is only one place that leaves the function that does not return some value (assuming `mark_safe()` does not return None), and that is the final `except urlfetch.Error, e: pass` clause. Look to see what error is actually being thrown there.

Comment: On production it's getting status 503. I'll try to find out why.

Comment: If you _must_ catch exceptions and then do nothing with them, use `logging.exception`, not `logging.error` - the former will output the stacktrace to the log.

Comment: I want to improve error handling but in this case it seems it is not an exceptions that occurs but instead a 503 from `result.status_code`

Comment: 503 is Service Unavailable (usually high load on the host). I find it hard to believe news.google would respond like that unless your code was somehow running many times concurrently. It could be their response to an attempted DoS. Conjecture, but still... What can you say about the server environment, also how many times would you expect to fetch() in a given request? I'm also wondering if caching the results would make a difference.

Comment: Thing is: It used to work. And it's only one request. I suppose I should switch to using Google Feeds API instead for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python functions that don't explicitly `return` anything will return `None`. If this code is returning `None` on your production server, it's probably because it's hitting that last `except: pass` block, as you mentioned.

Without reading the actual code (which I haven't), I'd say replace that `pass` with `return ''` to safely swallow the `urlfetch.Error` **or** decide what you want to happen in that case and implement some new code for that block.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was that it doesn't return 200 on production. I'm troubleshooting what the status could be but at leasat now I know where in the code it is.